# Unable to get htmlelement in winforms webbrowser control

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I'm developing automation program using winforms webbrowser control. I am able to get the htmlelement at the first few web pages. But i'm unable to get the htmlelement from certain pages and i'm using the same method like what i have done for the first few web pages (The few first pages htmlelement are retrieved successfully).

```
        HtmlElement createButton = this.extendedWebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("createButton");
        HtmlElement textArea = this.extendedWebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("query");
        HtmlElement filename = this.extendedWebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("filename");
        HtmlElement cancelBtn = this.extendedWebBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("cancelBtn");
```

it returned null and i have no idea why it return null althought the elements exist at the pages. Why and what to do so i can detect the html element? What kind of reasons can cause it is unable to be detected?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason of unable to get the Html Elements is because the Html Elements are embedded in the FrameSet. To access the FrameSet :

```
HtmlWindow docWindow = extendedWebBrowser2.Document.Window;

foreach (HtmlWindow frameWindow in docWindow.Frames)
{
  implementation code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was long time ago when I last tried using webbrowser control, but in old versions of .net there was a way to get using this way:

```
HtmlElement createButton = this.extendedWebBrowser2.Document.Body.GetElementById("createButton");
```

Notice `Body`.

Maybe it helps?

Comment: Tengiz, there are no Body.GetElementById attribute but does has Body.GetElementByTag. I have tried it on the first few pages and it works, but not working for the certain pages which have the problem that i'm facing now. Unable to detect the html element...

Comment: And, is the page DOM correct and complete? i.e. does it have <html>, <body> tags? including closing tags for them? And, is that page from internet or a local file?

Comment: Yes, the ID is correct. The page DOM correct and complete. It is from internet.

Comment: <a href="#" class="toolbar" id="aut_ExportReport_link" onclick="showExportWindow();" title="Export or report on data from the whole result set or from records selected individually">Exports &amp; Reports</a>

Comment: I clicked the above link, and it pop up a windows. i'm unable to keep trace of this windows element, although i can get its url. but i personally think whether it is a pop up windows or not ,it doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't get what you mean at all.

Comment: <input type="button" id="createButton" value="Create " class="displayButtonBold" onclick="if (top.createEnabled == true) top.exportframe.document.exportReportForm.cancel.click();" title="Click to create and deliver your export or report according to the options you have entered">   <-- this is the createButton that i'm trying to get, but it return null

Comment: The tag is closed using just ">", but it should using "/>", though I don't this this is the issue. I have no other thoughts except this can be related to the fact you are opening it from internet. I had issues when I loaded the page from internet and tried to tweak it.

Comment: Tengiz, i have found out the problems. Because the html elements are loaded in the html Frames. So what I have to do is to access the FrameSet to retrieve the html elements in it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you awaiting the document load event? The DOM is sometimes unavailable until the document has finished loading.

There's [an event on the browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) that you can subscribe to. If you do all your processing there it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Hi john, i have tried to execute the code above with a button click event after it is finished loaded. so i guess it is not caused by the loading problem. i really have no idea why the html element return null :(

Comment: Check the DocumenText for those elements, it could be a trivial spelling mistake. It's happened before.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (objBrowser.Document.Window != null) {
    foreach (HtmlWindow myframe in objBrowser.Document.Window.Frames) {
        HtmlElementCollection htmlControls = myframe.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("OPTION");
        foreach (HtmlElement optEle in htmlControls) {      
            optEle.SetAttribute("selected", "true");      
        }
    }
}
```